# Groupby and sum and insert as a new row with previous columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, transform

I am restructuring the data. The process contains two tasks:

1. inserting a new row by summing groupby.
2. creating a new column **Level**.

I have inserted expected output in picture 1 and picture 2.

The dataframe contains multiples columns. The sample data frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Competition']= ['EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL','EPL']
df ['Player']= ['Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno','Bruno']
df ['template'] = ['Def','Def','Pass','Pass','Actions','Actions','Attk','Attk','Other','Other']
df ['Stats'] = ['Def duels', ' ','Back passes', ' ','Dribbles', ' ','Goal','Assist','Possession Losses','Possession Losses [own half]']
df ['Stat1'] = [' ', 'Def duels Won',' ', 'Back passes[Acc]',' ', 'Dribbles[Suc]',' ',' ',' ',' ']
df ['Value'] = [5,2.5,60,55,5,2,2,1,3,1]
```

I want to sum the value using groupby the columns **Competition, Player, Template**. The value will be inserted as a new row just above the existing row. The expected data frame is as follows:

[image]

Based on the above-mentioned date frame, I would like to create a new column **Level** as follow:

[image]

```
> The Level as defined as follow: level= 1 if blank or no data in the
> columns **Stats,Stats1** level= 2 if blank or no data in the columns
> **Stats1** level= 3 if data in the columns **Stats1**
```

How would I do it?

Comment: The last row doesn't look right

Comment: Hi Sorry, it is supposed to be 2. I will update it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is `np.select`, you can modify this to your need:

```
# add extra rows with concat
df = pd.concat((df, df.groupby(['Competition','Player','template'])
                 .Value.sum().reset_index()
               )
         ).fillna(' ')

df['Level'] = np.select((df['Stat1'].ne(' '), df['Stats'].ne(' ')),
                        (3, 2), 1)
```

Output:

```
    Competition    Player    template    Stats                         Stat1               Value    Level
--  -------------  --------  ----------  ----------------------------  ----------------  -------  -------
 0  EPL            Bruno     Def         Def duels                                           5          2
 1  EPL            Bruno     Def                                       Def duels Won         2.5        3
 2  EPL            Bruno     Pass        Back passes                                        60          2
 3  EPL            Bruno     Pass                                      Back passes[Acc]     55          3
 4  EPL            Bruno     Actions     Dribbles                                            5          2
 5  EPL            Bruno     Actions                                   Dribbles[Suc]         2          3
 6  EPL            Bruno     Attk        Goal                                                2          2
 7  EPL            Bruno     Attk        Assist                                              1          2
 8  EPL            Bruno     Other       Possession Losses                                   3          2
 9  EPL            Bruno     Other       Possession Losses [own half]                        1          2
 0  EPL            Bruno     Actions                                                         7          1
 1  EPL            Bruno     Attk                                                            3          1
 2  EPL            Bruno     Def                                                             7.5        1
 3  EPL            Bruno     Other                                                           4          1
 4  EPL            Bruno     Pass                                                          115          1
```

Comment: Hi how abt the first part, groupby sum and insert as a new row? Thanks

Comment: post ur expected output dataframe for that as well. visuals are invaluable

Comment: @Zephyr see update. You will need to rearrange your data though.

Comment: I posted the expected data frames in two pictures. Thanks